# LINQ DateTime Aggregation with GroupBy and Group By

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-objects

I've  a List of TimeInterval data that are 30 minute apart as shown below:

```
List<TimeInterval> testData = new List<TimeInterval>();
testData.Add(new TimeInterval() { Start = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 6:00:00 AM"), End = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 6:30:00 AM"), Value = 1 });
testData.Add(new TimeInterval() { Start = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 6:30:00 AM"), End = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 7:00:00 AM"), Value = 1 });
testData.Add(new TimeInterval() { Start = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 7:00:00 AM"), End = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 7:30:00 AM"), Value = 1 });
testData.Add(new TimeInterval() { Start = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 7:30:00 AM"), End = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 8:00:00 AM"), Value = 1 });
.....
testData.Add(new TimeInterval() { Start = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-10 7:00:00 AM"), End = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-10 7:30:00 AM"), Value = 20 });
testData.Add(new TimeInterval() { Start = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-10 7:30:00 AM"), End = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-10 8:00:00 AM"), Value = 10 });
................... up to N number of N number of years.


public class TimeInterval
    {
       public DateTime Start { get; set; }
       public DateTime End { get; set; }
       public decimal Value { get; set; }

    }
```

Could someone please suggest the best way to aggregate the above data to :

> 1. Hour
> 2. Day
> 3. Week
> 4. Month
> 5. Year

I tried with suggested solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498831/linq-aggregate-30-minute-interval-to-hour) but none of them seem to cater the above requirements. Thanks for your help.

The expected result for Hour for given example above is:

```
Lists Of:

TimeInterval() { Start = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 6:00:00 AM"), End = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 7:00:00 AM"), Value = 2 }
TimeInterval() { Start = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 7:00:00 AM"), End = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-09 8:00:00 AM"), Value = 2 }
...
TimeInterval() { Start = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-10 7:00:00 AM"), End = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-10 8:00:00 AM"), Value = 2 }
```

For Days, it will be total for the day.
for week, it will be total for a whole week etc. basically sum the Value for given aggregation type.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more precise? Why does TimeInterval have Start and StartDate properties? How do you want to aggregate? What do you want to aggregate? Maybe you want to sum the timespan between start and end of each TimeInterval, e.g. 30 min + 30 min + ... = X min = Y hours...) Or do you want to count the number of different days, e.g. 2012-05-09 + 2012-05-10 = 2 days? Or...??

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Interval> CreatHourIntervals(DateTime start, int count, int intervalValue, int val)
{
    return     Enumerable.Range(0,count)
               .Select(x=> new Interval
                               {
                                 StartDate = start.AddHours(x*intervalValue), 
                                 EndDate = start.AddHours((x + 1)*intervalValue),
                                 value = val
                               }
                         ).ToList(); 
}
```

**Description**

**start:** is start date for the first item in the interval.

**count:** is the number of intervals you want.

**intervalValue:** is difference between intervals, e.g in hour case, this can vary between 1,12 (also it can be fractional). e.g if you set it to `2`, each interval length is `2` hour.

For other types you can write related method yourself.

Comment: Give that I've a listofIntervals e.g. testData, how do I call this function

Comment: @nilpun, `List<TimeInterval> testHourData = CreatHourIntervals(.....);` is there anything ambiguous?

Comment: Yep, given List<TimeInterval> testData we need to calculate the hour aggregation, day,week,month etc.

Comment: @nilpun, I couldn't understand what you mean?